# detect carriage return in UITextField in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How would I detect a carriage return for a UITextView in iOS?

I am currently just watching this field for a period of time but want to improve on this a bit:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSLog(@"text editing started: %i", scanning);

    if (!scanning) {
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(checkText:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        scanning = YES;
        [self.scannedItems scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

So I would want to call a function after the return is found, currently I call checkText after 1 second.

Comment: It might help if you gave more context as to what you are trying to do and why.  You could always check the text for carriage return before you assign a string as the text to the UITextField.  If the user is entering text, you could check each keystroke for the carriage return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with this:
`- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField`

I presume its also possible to look at the character value in the code you posted. Return was int value of 13 the last time I needed to look at it directly.